# Phonegap Build Firebase push notification on IOS not working (but working on Android)

Tags: ios, push-notification, phonegap-build, phonegap

Can anybody help me solve the following issue with my Phonegap hybrid app? I'm using Phonegap Build to process the data.

My ios devices aren't receiving push notifications but my android devices are.
I'm using the following data in config.xml:

```
 ...
 <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-9.0.0" />  
 <platform name="android">
     <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
 </platform>
 <platform name="ios">
     <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />    
 </platform>
 <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="2.1.3">
     <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
 </plugin>    
 ..
```

My payload looks like this...

```
  $data = [
         "title"             =>$titlenotification,  
         "message"           => $message,
         "content_available" => "1",
  ];

  $fields =  [
        'registration_ids'   => $registrationtokens,          
        'data'               => $data,                         
        "priority"           => "high",
        "content_available"  => true,
  ];
```

...and my push initialisation in the app looks like this...

```
   var push = PushNotification.init({
        android: {
          senderID: senderId,  
          iconColor: "#d4edda",
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          icon: 'notification_icon',
          sound: true,
          vibrate: true,
        },
        browser: {},
        ios: {
          senderID: senderId,  
          sound: true,
          vibration: true,
          badge: true
        },
        windows: {}
      }
  );
```

I'm using an App Store Production provision and I'm testing the app through Testflight.

Many thanks.

Comment: The app receives push notificatons when I test it directly through Firebase Cloud. It just isn't receiving it using my own payload sender code (using the payload you see above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to ensure that the correct APN and profile was in use. Push notification had not been included on the APN, and the profile must be for "prodduction" not development.

I hope that helps someone else.